# Using 'Link to a Document' content type to link to an EXTERNAL document which exceeds SharePoint file size limit

Tags: 2010, document-library, content-type, document, hyperlink

**Background**

I've created a SharePoint page for the purpose of making a number of on-demand videos available to staff. These videos are saved on a networked share drive that all staff have access to. Unfortunately, I cannot upload them to SharePoint because they exceed the file size limit. So, at present I am just linking to them from my SharePoint page.

**The problem**

The page I've designed works fine. Staff can click on the links and the videos open. However, there is no way for me to get stats on the number of views each video has because they are not stored on SharePoint.

So, to try and get around this, I tried adding 'documents' to one of our SharePoint document libraries using the *Link to a Document* function. My thinking was that on my SharePoint page I could just link to these 'document links' within the document library instead of directly to the videos. I would then have stats on how many times these links were accessed.

However, to my surprise, this doesn't work because the videos I am linking to exceed the SharePoint file size limit. **I find this bizarre - after all, the videos are not being uploaded to the SharePoint server,** I am merely trying to *link* to them via the *Link to a Document* function. And linking to them works fine from my SharePoint page, so why not using this method as well?

**What I've already tried**

Unfortunately increasing the SharePoint file size limit is **not** an option. Also, the videos cannot be compressed any further (I've already got them down to the lowest usable file size).

I've also tried using the *Link to a Document* function to browse to another file below the file-size limit and then in the properties entering the file path of the real file (i.e. the video file) into the URL field. This works fine when I test it with the *Click here to test* option, but after I Check it in and try clicking on the link it opens the original file, not the file I've added the file path for.

I know I could just create a separate SharePoint page for each video, but besides the fact that is a lot of extra work, it's also not 100% accurate as there is no certainty that a person viewing a particular page also viewed the video linked to from that page.

**So, how do I get around this conundrum? Is there a way to use the *Link to a Document* function when linking to an *external* document that exceeds the internal file size limit of SharePoint?**